# Почему не меняется текст кнопки при анимации

Tags: java, android, objectanimator

Когда я нажимаю первый раз, кнопки идут и возвращаются с другими буквами, но когда я нажимаю снова, ничего не происходит:

```
int d = -1; Строка btnanim = "0";
```

Как сделать его анимированным, когда я снова нажимаю на кнопку?

```
public void b_b1(View v) {
    if (this.btnanim == "AB") {
        btn("CD");
        return;
    }
    if (this.btnanim == "CD") {
            btn("EF");
            return;
        }
        if (this.btnanim == "EF") {
            btn("GH");
            return;
        }
    btn("AB");
}
```

Без анимации текст изменяется при каждом клике

```
void btn(String str) {
    this.btnanim = str;
    this.timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        ObjectAnimator anim;
        LinearLayout bgroup = (LinearLayout) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.bg);
        Button b1 = (Button) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        Button b2 = (Button) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.b2);

        public void run() {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity.this.d += 1;
                        switch (MainActivity.this.d) {
                            case 0:
                                anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bgroup, "translationX", bgroup.getWidth() * 2);
                                anim.setDuration(500L).start();
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bgroup, "translationX", -bgroup.getWidth() * 2);
                                anim.setDuration(0L).start();
                                anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bgroup, "translationX", 0);
                                anim.setDuration(500L).start();
                                switch (MainActivity.this.btnanim) {
                                    case "AB":
                                        b1.setText("A");
                                        b2.setText("B");
                                        break;
                                    case "CD":
                                        b1.setText("C");
                                        b2.setText("D");
                                        break;
                                    case "EF":
                                        b1.setText("E");
                                        b2.setText("F");
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0L, 100L);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MainActivity.this.btnanim = "AB";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в

```
switch (MainActivity.this.d) {

case 0:
...

case 5:
```

срабатывает при `0` и `5`

Здесь

```
MainActivity.this.d += 1;
```

вы прибавляете к

```
int d = -1;
```

то есть меняете значение переменной. Было `-1`, стало `0` сработало `case 0:`. потом стало `1` - `case` обрабатывающего это значение уже нет

Может здесь проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Грубо говоря здесь она работает как секунда. При `5`сработало `case 5:` анимация возвращается и стоит на месте. Но надо чтоб она вернулась начала цикла опять при повторном нажатии кнопки я так думаю.

Все получилась. Нужно было задать самом методе `this.d=-1;`. В чем-то [TimurVI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190461/timurvi) был прав.